# Python script to read Json like dictionary and able to overwrite json file parameters as command line argument

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a valid JSON file which needs to be read by a python script using command line argument.

So in command line:

> python3 myscript.py -i mytest.json

Then it should output all the data that I have in the Json file.

mytest.json

```
[{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Jeanette",
"last_name": "Penddreth",
"email": "jpenddreth0@census.gov",
"gender": "Female",
"ip_address": "26.58.193.2"
}]
```

Then again, if I want to overwrite the Json data using commandline argument for example:

> python3 myscript.py -i mytest.json --first_name=John --last_name=Doe

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fname=json.loads(open('fname').read()
with open('fname','w') as f:
   f.write(json.dumps(fname))
```

Basically what you need to do is to load the entire json file into a dict, add your data and write it back.

Comment: This could be one way. I solved the problem using docopt module

Comment: @habisl If it's more efficient I'd love to read about it. Any links?

Comment: You can check my solution here: 
https://github.com/habisl/My-Python-Workplace/blob/master/jsonreader.py